# Need help solving matrices questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have worked out how to solve some of these however am particularly stuck on questions 3, 4.b and 5. If anyone could help explain how to solve any of the questions that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image: Matrices questions]

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Which question are you talking about? How did you use the calculator to solve $2,3$?

Comment: I'm having trouble with all of these, but I'm mainly stuck on 3, 4.b and 5

Comment: I'm fine with question 1 and 2 ( sorry to be unspecific I solved 2 without the use of a calculator) and am confused with question 3

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

For $3$, just assume $A=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}$. Find $AB^T$ and check its determinant.

In $4(b)$, note that we can post-multiply by $A^{-1}$ on both sides of $XA=B$ to obtain $XAA^{-1}=XI_2=X=BA^{-1}$.

For $5$, you just have to show that $A^3=A$ through regular matrix multiplication. Note that you will find $A^2=I_2$, so the former follows naturally and need not be computed. Now, since $A^2=I_2,(A^2)^{13}=A^{26}=I_2^{13}=I_2$, which means $A^{27}=A$.

Comment: thanks for the help. Quick question though. How would I find the product of AB when they have the same dimensions?

Comment: @Jacobdodd56 You have to find the product of $A$ and the transpose of $B$, i.e. $B^T$.